# GULP : Reference Error: 'src' is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, gulp

i'm getting this error on this line:

```
  return src('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
.pipe(dest("src/js"))
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

I don't have a clue what's going on, Any suggestions?

**My code:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');



function sass(){

 return src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss','src/sass/*.sass'])
 .pipe(sass())
 .pipe(dest("src/css"))
 .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}


function js(){
 return src('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
.pipe(dest("src/js"))
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
}


function serve(){

  browserSync.init({ 
    server: "./src"
});

watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss','src/sass/*.sass'],sass());
watch("../HSM/*.html").on('change',browserSync.reload);
}

function Default () {

  js(); 
  serve();
}

exports.default = Default;
```

I already check  the documentation about this new version of gulp everything seems fine and it should work correctly butat the time to  run it i  get that reference error.

Comment: Use `gulp.src` or this form: `const { src, dest, watch } = require('gulp');`

Comment: is like the  cout and cin  in c++
you have to put the "using std" instruction to use cout and cin without de std.cin (something like that) 

Thank you!